# I need to show only future one month dates in the date picker from the start date selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
enter code here
```

```js
$("#StartDate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
        if (this.id == 'StartDate') {
            //console.log(selectedDate);//2014-12-30
            var arr = selectedDate.split("/");
            var date = new Date(arr[2]+"-"+arr[1]+"-"+arr[0]);
            var d = date.getDate();
            var m = date.getMonth();
            var y = date.getFullYear();
            var minDate = new Date(y, m, d + 1);
            $("#EndDate").datepicker('setDate', minDate);

        }
    }
});
$("#EndDate").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});
```

```html
<input id="StartDate" type="text"  name="StartDate">
<input id="EndDate" class="datepicker" type="text"  name="EndDate">
```

Any required plugins given are appreciable.

Here the requirement is like I have two input fields one is for start date and another is for end date for e.g. if the select start date as 21-05-2020 and auto automatically the end date input filed should fetch the future one month dates as 21-06-2020. finally the output should be like start date: 21-05-2020 to end date: 21-06-2020.

Comment: and when i using this code in my project in eclipse the start date is fetching but the end date is not fetching

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add both **minDate** and **maxDate** properties, something like this (click the **Run code snippet** button down below for a live demo):

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    minDate: 0, // ban dates in the past
    maxDate: "+1M" // allow only 1 month in the future
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<body>
  <p>My cool date Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Here the requirement is like I have two input fields one is for start date and another is for end date for e.g. if the select start date as 21-05-2020 and auto automatically the end date input filed should fetch the future one month dates as 21-06-2020.

finally the output should be like start date: 21-05-2020 to end date: 21-06-2020.

Comment: You mean same date of next month or date that comes after 30 day? what if the current month is feb?